# Laravel 5 asset helper function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I added a new writable folder to the public folder in Laravel 5 called uploads. All the other folders ( css, images, js ) are fine when I wrap them in the asset() helper function. The uploads directory, however, is not working right. The images that are in there are not showing up, I only see a broken image. When I go in through firebug and remove the 'public' folder from the path the images show fine. Its almost like I need to somehow tell Laravel that uploads is not in public.

Any one know why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Edit:
Here is a link with the uploads folder:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/uploads') }}/{{$med->media_link}}.{{$med->media_extension}}">
```

it produces:

```
<img src="http://website.com/public/uploads/4b9asdqwdqwdaasd.jpg">
```

Here is a link with the logo which is just in an images folder in the public directory:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images')}}/{{Session::get('site_folder')}}/logo.png">
```

it produces:

```
<img src="http://website.com/public/images/website/logo.png" alt="website">
```

Site folder is something I set in session that is specific to the group using it. For this question its irrelevant but I wanted to put it in there to show exactly how it is.

Comment: Please post a sample of how you are setting the URLs for the images. Are you using `asset` like for the other resources that you say are working?

Comment: @Bogdan edited above

Comment: And the logo is displayed while the uploaded image is not?

Comment: @Bogdan correct. I almost feel like I need to somehow register with the framework that uploads is in the public directory but it doesn't make sense. I have read everything out there on this and I cannot seem to find the answer.

Comment: That's just strange, since I assume you've set the document root for the server to the `public` directory, then all URL paths should only work _without_ the `/public` part in them, so the logo should not be displayed. Can you please post the directory structure in your `public` directory.

Comment: @Bogdan that reminded me that when I started this project I pulled all directories out of the public folder and into the "root" because I was afraid that the urls would be domain.com/public/about.. etc. I was knew to Laravel and still trying to figure it out. I remember having to make some adjustments to the settings when I did that, let me take a look at my notes to see what I did and maybe that has something to it.

Comment: It is still strange that one works and the other doesn't though.

Comment: **NOTE:** `{{}}` is for version 4. `{!! !!}` is for version 5.1

Comment: @aldrin27 ?? Double curly braces is the **preferred** way to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: @Scott I'm a bit confused since we can't see your directory structure. Are you saying that the uploads directory is not inside your public directory?

Comment: Hi @ThomasKim yes it is in the public directory. Inside the public directory I have css, js, images, uploads, bootstrap and font awesome. When I installed Laravel 5.0 originally I moved all the files up to the root directory then added those asset folders to the actual public directory.

Comment: I found the issue and wanted to share it. It was not really an issue after all. At some point I changed up something that put the uploads directory inside the root so all my images were actually going there instead of the public directory. I just finally saw this because I went in through ftp ( I generally only use command line ) and noticed the folder. I knew this did not make logical sense. I removed the folder, changed the upload script and its working. Thanks everyone for the help.